# How to excute a Lua compiled file and call functions with custom global environment in LuaJ?

Tags: java, lua, precompiled, luaj

I have precompiled Lua script with ScriptEngine.

```
private void preCompile(){
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    engine = manager.getEngineByName("luaj");
    if(engine instanceof Compilable){
        try {
            compScript = ((Compilable)engine).compile(scriptContent);
        }catch (ScriptException se){
            System.err.println(se.getMessage());
        }
    }else{
        System.err.println("Engine can't compile code!");
    }
```

And I can also execute it with eval() function and call the functions in the Script with LuaFunction.invoke(LuaValue).

```
public Object callFunction(String funcName, Object[] args){
    preCompile();
    Bindings script_bindings = new SimpleBindings();
    try{
        compScript.eval(script_bindings);
        LuaFunction luafunc = (LuaFunction)script_bindings.get(funcName);
        LuaValue[] luaValues = new LuaValue[args.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; ++i){
            luaValues[i] = CoerceJavaToLua.coerce(args[i]);
        }
        result = luafunc.invoke(luaValues);
    }catch (ScriptException se){
        System.out.println(se.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Here Is The Problem:**

I can executed script with Java API, but what I want to do is making a custom environment by using Global.

so I create Global object and load needed libs like this:

```
private void LoadScript(){
    globals = new Globals();
    globals.load(new JseBaseLib());
    globals.load(new PackageLib());
    globals.load(new StringLib());
    globals.load(new Bit32Lib());
    globals.load(new TableLib());
    LoadState.install(globals);
    LuaC.install(globals);
```

Now I just don't know how to link 'globals' to the compiled file(compScript). I have tried the global compiled function

```
Prototype chunk = globals.compilePrototype(new StringReader(script), "script");
```

`chunk.call()` can be used to execute script, but I still don't know how to call the functions(with or without arguments) in script by 'chunk' or 'compScript' in my custom 'globals' environment.

**In addition, is `globals.load()` function compile script file? I just want to compile script once and reuse it.**

Comment: Did you see the `invokemethod` methods which do accept a function name?

Answer (score 0):

The chunk must be obtained with `globals.load`. Then you can `call` the chunk and get the lua function you want from the globals, assuming your function is defined as a global. If it is `local`, you cannot use it.

```
LuaValue chunk = globals.load(script, "script");
chunk.call();
LuaValue func = globals.get(functionName);
func.call(args);
```

Comment: They're using their own ScriptEngine, they don't have access to the globals in that regard. They're asking how they can set the globals for said ScriptEngine themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The class `LuajContext` has an exposed, public `globals` value ([source code reference](https://github.com/luaj/luaj/blob/daf3da94e3cdba0ac6a289148d7e38bd53d3fe64/src/jse/org/luaj/vm2/script/LuajContext.java#L45)). By getting the context from the engine and casting it to LuajContext, you can work with the table (you should not need to create your own globals, by the way; the defaults are constructed in the context's constructor)

```
LuajContext context = (LuajContext) e.getContext();
System.out.println(context.globals);
```